# Error in IndexOutOfBoundsException using Loop from Database another class Java

Tags: java, mysql

I'm getting an `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`. This is my code:

`Main.java`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ordersList.size(); i++) {
    if (ordersList.get(i).getUser_id() == ordersList.get(i)
            .getPersonsList().get(i).getId()) {
        System.out.println("Order: "
                + ordersList.get(i).getId()
                + "Person"
                + ordersList.get(i).getPersonsList().get(i)
                        .getName());
    }
}
```

`Database.java`:

```
MysqlPrepareStat = MysqlConn.prepareStatement(insertQueryStatement);
ResultSet result = MysqlPrepareStat.executeQuery();
while (result.next()) {
    Orders orders = new Orders();
    orders.setId(result.getInt("o.id"));
    orders.setDate(result.getString("o.date_time"));
    orders.setQuantity(result.getInt("o.quantity"));
    Person persons = new Person();
    orders.setUser_id(result.getInt("u.id"));
    persons.setName(result.getString("u.name"));
    persons.setSobrename(result.getString("u.sobrename"));
    persons.setEmail(result.getString("u.email"));
    persons.setId(result.getInt("u.id"));
    persons.setCellphone(result.getInt("u.telefone"));
    orders.addPerson(persons);
    orderList.add(orders);
}
```

I want to get the Persons with the same id from Orders that i have declared inside orderList

```
public List<Person> getPersonsList() {
    return personsList;
}


public void addPerson(Person person) {
    personsList.add(person);
}
```

Comment: You can't use the same index for orders and persons simultaneously.

Comment: If you can see, i´m using orders.user_id == person.getId like database operations.

Comment: (ordersList.get(i).getUser_id() is the foreign key that is equals to person.getId @shmosel

Comment: @CodeCoding what shmosel means is you are calling `getPersonsList().get(i)` with the index i you are using to iterate over `ordersList`  without any checks if personlist has that element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please fix code inside your `Main.java`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ordersList.size(); i++) {
    if (ordersList.get(i).getUser_id() ==
            ordersList.get(i).getPersonsList().get(0).getId()) {
        System.out.println("Order: "+ ordersList.get(i).getId()+
            "Person"+ ordersList.get(i).getPersonsList().get(0).getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine bro!

Comment: Sure. Enjoy ! :)

Answer (score 1):

if (ordersList.get(i).getUser_id() == ordersList.get(i)
                            .getPersonsList().get(0).getId())

You are adding PersonList to each order and that PersonList has only one person for each order. So It is advised to do get(0) rather than get(i).